# ScrollViewer Issue with StackPanel in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I put StackPanel into ScrollViewr, When scrolling to last item it returns back to its old position.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,20">
<StackPanel>
  //Textblocks and Textboxes ...
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

After search i found that:
[ItemsControl, VirtualizingStackPanel and ScrollViewer height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576623/itemscontrol-virtualizingstackpanel-and-scrollviewer-height?rq=1)

I changed my code to:

```
<StackPanel>
  //Textblocks and Textboxes ...
</StackPanel>
<ScrollViewer>
<VirtualizingStackPanel />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

I can't set CanContentScroll="True" as i can't find it.
Also  make exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: A VirtualizingPanel is not nested in an ItemsControl. VirtualizingPanel must be nested in ItemsControl to get and show items.

What must i do, to enable scrolling without returning back to its old position?

Regards,

Comment: Did you get bounce back effect in the first attempt? Like you couldn't really scroll, it was merely stretched?

Comment: No, it scroll vertically but once i reach last item and remove my finger it return back to the top again.

Comment: Can you scroll to the *half* of the list without auto scroll to the top?

Comment: Exactly I have 4 textboxes, I enter data at 1st one, I want to scroll to the last to write in it but, it scroll to just 2nd one and can't reach the last.

Comment: Can you post the full snippet with the surrounding code for the scroll viewer? Not the inside, but the outside XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search again ...
I found this Post which solve the problem of Scrolling return to old position when open keyboard.

[Scrolling page with keyboard shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482097/scrolling-page-with-keyboard-shown?rq=1)

code after updates:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<StackPanel Height="700">
  //Textblocks and Textboxes ...
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```